# Range variable not defined

Tags: excel, vba

I've been tasked to correct someone elses code and it's not commented and I'm not a VBA pro. My question is, how is the cell variable defined as a specific cell in the spreadsheet.
This is the part I'm talking about:     `go.Range("B" & b).Value = cell`

First he sets it to be a Range dimension, and then all of a sudden it's being set equal to a cell, but how does it know that it contains anything?

Let me know if I'm being too vague

```
    Dim batch As Worksheet
    Dim go As Worksheet
    Set batch = Worksheets("BATCHES")
    Set go = Worksheets("GoLive")

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim idag As Date
    Dim modtaget As Date
    idag = Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD")


b = 10
Dim N As Integer



For Each cell In batch.Range("tbl_batches[BATCH_NO]")

        If batch.Cells(cell.Row, batch.Range("tbl_batches[PKQA]").Column) <> "" And batch.Cells(cell.Row, batch.Range("tbl_batches[PGAQA]").Column) = "" Then

                If batch.Cells(cell.Row, batch.Range("tbl_batches[QARP]").Column) = "" Then
                    go.Range("B" & b).Value = cell

                    modtaget = batch.Cells(cell.Row, batch.Range("tbl_batches[PKQA]").Column)
                    go.Range("C" & b).Value = modtaget

                    N = Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(modtaget, idag)
                    go.Range("D" & b).Value = N

                    b = b + 1
```

Comment: Since `cell` is a `Range` object, it also contains a value (or is empty). So this "someone else" made it such that `go.Range("B" & b).Value` will be equal to `cell` its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question: ***how is the cell variable defined as a specific cell in the spreadsheet***?

The original author has created a loop (commonly known as a FOR..NEXT loop) that iterates through each child item of, in this case, a range `batch.Range("tbl_batches[BATCH_NO]")`. (If not specified otherwise, such as `Columns`, or `Rows` - the child item defaults to `Cells`)

```
For Each cell In batch.Range("tbl_batches[BATCH_NO]")
```

This could (and probably should) read:

```
For Each cell In batch.Range("tbl_batches[BATCH_NO]").Cells
```

So each time the loop runs, it uses the next cell from the range specified and loads it to a Range object called `cell` - which is then used within the loop. This is why it's not always the best idea to name your cell range `cell` - as it can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`go.Range("B" & b).Value = cell.value`